# Who is the subject in the sentence「その娘にまで苦しめられなきゃいけないの…」

Tags: translation, particle-に, conjugations, manga, passive-voice

> どうしてあの男だけじゃなくその娘にまで苦しめられなきゃいけないの…

I have came across this sentence and have first assumed that it meant something along the lines of

> Why am I not only being tormented by that man, but also his daughter...

The reason is that 苦しめる seems to be in its passive form 苦しめられる, and 娘 is marked by に, indicating that the daughter performs the action, and the implied subject (the speaker) receives it.

However, translating tools online give me the opposite causality, and so does a translator who worked on that manga.

Is my reasoning incorrect, and if so, where did I get that wrong?

> [image: 工場夜景]

Comment: Machine translation is pretty universally bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning seems correct (except that you ignored the なきゃいけない part). The grammatical subject of the sentence is the speaker, and 苦しめられる is in the passive voice. As is clearly depicted in the picture, not only あの男 but also その娘 are causing trouble to the speaker.

For reference, here are the results of translating this sentence with several translation/AI engines:

> どうしてあの男だけじゃなくその娘にまで苦しめられなきゃいけないの…
>
> - [DeepL Translate] Why should I be tormented not only by that man, but also by his daughter...
> - [ChatGPT (GPT-4)] Why do I have to suffer not only because of that man but also because of that girl...
> - [Google Translate] I really have to suffer not only from that man but also from that girl...
> - [Microsoft Bing Translator] ❌Why do I have to torment not only that man but also his daughter ...

Among these, Bing's translation is indeed incorrect. The others seem to be correct to me, though they use different English constructions to convey the idea. Note that その娘 can be either "his daughter" or "that girl". This is purely context-dependent, so please see the previous pages.